# How to Delay execution until an element has loaded on a modal to then alter the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a modal on it.  In my javascript after the modal is opened I need to look for a particular div and hide it and then show it again if a certain value is changed.

The problem is when the function that loads the modal runs the content hasn't rendered yet.  I was trying to call monitorForVaultCardGroup() to look for the field ever 100ms, then return when it was found.  Then, with the reference valid call hide().

```
function monitorForVaultCardGroup() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const vaultCardGroup = $("[data-group=VaultCardGroup]");
                    if (vaultCardGroup.length > 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    monitorForVaultCardGroup();
                }, 100);
            }

            monitorForVaultCardGroup();
            
            vaultCardGroup.hide();
```

Why does the reference not seem to resolve when .hide() is called?

Comment: isnt `vaultCardGroup` defined inside the `monitorForVaultCardGroup()` whereas you try to reference it outside the function ? Also, how do you load the modal content ?

Comment: Javascript sounds like its a little overkill. Why not just hide it by default via CSS?